# list not entering first input

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, raw-input

I am noob and I am working on this python project and i cant get the first input entered by the user in a array my code. Thanks in advance
Here is my code:

```
def ask():
    user_input = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    user_input_array = []
    count = 0
    quits = 'done'

    while user_input != quits:
        user_input = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        try:
            if type(user_input) == str:
                num = int(user_input)
                user_input_array.append(num)
                count = count + 1

        except:
            print("Invalid input")

    while user_input == quits:
        #user_input_array.remove('done')
        print ("done")
        print ('Count: ', count)
        print (user_input_array)
        break
ask()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you never put it in there.

```
def ask():
    user_input = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    user_input_array = [user_input] # Create the list with the original input
    ...
```

With the above, the first thing entered by the user is placed in the list when the list is created. You might want to do your checks before this

Answer (score 0):

```
  def ask():
        user_input = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        user_input_array = []
        count = 0 
        quits = 'done'

        while user_input != quits:
            user_input = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
            try:
                if type(user_input) == str:
                    num = int(user_input)
                    user_input_array.append(num)
                    count = count + 1 

            except:
                    if user_input == quits:
                            #user_input_array.remove('done')
                            print ("done")
                            print ('Count: ', count)
                            print (user_input_array)
                    else:
                            print("Invalid input")


    ask()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not add your initial input to the array. Instead you enter the loop and ask for another input and check then add that to the array. You should ask for all inputs within the loop, as this means you only need one `raw_input` and one check for the done value.

A common way to do this is to go into an infinite loop and only exit when you read the value `done`. Like so

```
def ask():

    user_input_array = []

    while True:

        user_input = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

        if user_input == 'done':
            break

        try:
            user_input_array.append(int(user_input))    
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")

    print ("done")
    print ('Count: ', len(user_input_array))
    print (user_input_array)

ask()
```

Note that this achieves the desired effect with no repetition. You also don't need to keep a count of how many elements you added, as the list has a `len` function which will tell you that.